# Selecting unique values in a particular column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I tried using the following:

```
awk '{print $1}' your_file | sort | uniq
```

However, the output does not turn out as expected.
Here are examples of what values in the column I am interested in looks like:

```
"Non-cancer illness code, self-reported"
"Birth weight known"
```

Could the empty spaces in each field be causing the problem? If so, how can I resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: What delimiter is the file using to delimit the data in the columns from each other?

Comment: "*the output does not turn out as expected*". You neither show us the actual output nor the input. How should we be able to help if we don't know what you want to do, especially as it is not really clear what you want from your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry for not providing sufficient details!
Output looks like this (not the full one because it is very long but just a few lines to give you an idea):
procedures
code
to
dependent

Only parts of the actual values in the column turn up. For instance, instead of "Birth weight known", only "weight" turns up.

Comment: @they I think the delimiter is tab

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add a few example lines from your input file (_actual, entire lines_) and ii) show us the output you expect from that example.

Comment: Find out if your delimiter is tab or not and also tell us if all fields are quoted and whether or not tabs or double quotes or newlines can exist within the quoted fields. [edit] your question to provide all missing information and full-record examples so we can best help you.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first tab-delimited field from a file using `awk`, make sure to set the field separator to a tab character.  As shown below, you do this by giving the option-argument `\t` to the `-F` option.

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '{ print $1 }' file
```

It would also be relatively easy to use `cut` here as the tab character is its default delimiter, and you don't need to do any other fancy processing:

```bsh
cut -f 1 file
```

Pass this through `sort | uniq` to get the unique lines, or through `sort -u` if you want to do less typing.

---

You are running into the issue that `awk` by default uses *any whitespace* (runs of tabs or spaces) as its delimiter, and your first field contains spaces, causing the utility to misinterpret the first *word* as the first field.

Comment: This worked, thank you!